# rails custom method that get models on has many through assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think i'm having trouble finding the answer because I don't know what the terminology is.

heres the run down

I have three models; User, Game, UserRole

A Game

```
has_many :user_roles
has_many :users, through: :user_roles
```

A User

```
has_many :user_roles
has_many :games, through: :user_roles
```

A User role looks like this

```
create_table "user_roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "role",       default: "unknown role"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "game_id"
end
```

What i want is a method on the game model (I think thats where it should go) that allows me to get a list of users based on a given role the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *allows me to get a list of users based on a given role*

If that is what you want to achieve. Then you could add following `scope` in `User` model:

```
scope :role_based_users, ->(role, game_id) { 
  joins(:user_roles).where("user_roles.role = ? and user_roles.game_id = ?", role, game_id) 
}
```

which you can access as

```
## Replace role_string with actual role and game_id with id of an existing game
User.role_based_users(role_string, game_id)
```

The above will give you all the users with `role = role_string` for a particular game.

> *What i want is a method on the game model (I think thats where it should go)*

I would suggest you to add the `scope` in `User` model as you want to list the `users` and not the `games`.

Comment: I was thinking that it should be on the game model because what I want are users with a given role for that game.  Ultimately a json serialization of the game model needs to be spat out.  I'm using active_model_serializers to do this.  I have something sort of working in the debate serializer [ attribute :playerA, serializer: API::V1::UserSerializer, root: 'playerA'] but this doesn't seem to be using my custom serializer.

Comment: Still  you need to retrieve users and not games. See my updated answer, that should take care of the specific game part.